# ¿Cómo puedo extraer un fragmento de un archivo .txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Supongamos que tengo la siguiente linea de texto en un archivo.txt

```
BF2D@Hj04127885@rREF Z1@iEST@p@l468@n192@e35,490@d8@g@s32@v@Gl80@w-90@l80@w-90@l120@w-90@l80@w-90@l120@w-90@l80@w0@Pw1@
```

Yo solo quiero extraer los valores que están después de la letra `l`. En este caso quiero extraer los valores `468` , `80` ,`80` ,`120` , `80` , `120` , `80` .Me gustaría extraerlos con Python.

Comment: Bienvenido Federico Moontero a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Como sugerencia adicional, agrega algún comentario o código de lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora, ya que tu pregunta, planteada de esta forma, parece del tipo "Hagan mi tarea/trabajo", que no suele ser algo bien recibido por la comunidad. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza expresiones regulares:

```
    import re

   # extraer los valores que están después de la letra l.
    regex = r"(?<=(l))(\d+)"
    test_str = "BF2D@Hj04127885@rREF Z1@iEST@p@l468@n192@e35,490@d8@g@s32@v@Gl80@w-90@l80@w-90@l120@w-90@l80@w-90@l120@w-90@l80@w0@Pw1@"

    matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
    l=[m.groups()[1]  for matchNum,m  in enumerate(matches)]
    print(l)
```

Resultado:

```
    [ '468', '80', '80', '120', '80', '120', '80']
```

Answer (score 1):

Federico, hola, te dejo el siguiente codigo que use para hacer lo que pides, basicamente como los numeros estan despues de la l puedes hacer un .split() del string dado ese caracter (la "l"):

```
    string = 'BF2D@Hj04127885@rREF Z1@iEST@p@l468@n192@e35,490@d8@g@s32@v@Gl80@w-        90@l80@w-90@l120@w-90@l80@w-90@l120@w-90@l80@w0@Pw1@'
    string = string.split('l')
    print(string)
    #['BF2D@Hj04127885@rREF Z1@iEST@p@', '468@n192@e35,490@d8@g@s32@v@G', '80@w-90@', '80@w-90@', '120@w-90@', '80@w-90@', '120@w-90@', '80@w0@Pw1@']
```

Luego con eso ya separado, podemos volver a hacer un split pero ahora dado el caracter "@", y como sabes que el numero es lo primero en cada valor de la lista que se genero dado el primer split, puedes imprimir solo dicho valor, lo que dije en codigo se veria mas o menos asi:

```
    numbers = [int(i.split('@')[0]) for i in string[1:len(string)]]
    print(numbers)
    #[468, 80, 80, 120, 80, 120, 80]
```

Answer (score 0):

El que lo hizo con re está genial, pero por si acaso más simple:

```
test_str = "BF2D@Hj04127885@rREF Z1@iEST@p@l468@n192@e35,490@d8@g@s32@v@Gl80@w-90@l80@w-90@l120@w-90@l80@w-90@l120@w-90@l80@w0@Pw1@"
# creamos una lista en la que pondremos los números que empiecen con L
numeros_l = []


a = test_str.split('@')  # Separamos la linea por las '@', lo que nos crea una lista: 'a'

for item in a:                         # Iteramos la lista "por cada item en a"
  if item.startswith('l'):             # "Si el item empieza con L"
    numeros_l.append(item.strip('l'))  # "Lo agregamos a la lista 'numeros_l"

print(numeros_l)  # Resultado: una lista con todos los números que empiezan con 'L'
['468', '80', '120', '80', '120', '80']
```

Saludos!

Comment: Saludos, considera que una explicación a tu código lo haría mas fácil de entender

Comment: Tienes razón, edité respuesta para agregar una explicación paso por paso, espero te sirva, Saludos.-